# In angular2 select option with ng-repeat for array of objects is not working. Its giving [Object object] instead of real object

Tags: object, select, angular

In angular 2 select options with ngRepeat for array of string is working fine, but its not working as expected when the data is array of object. ngModel is displaying as '[Object object]' instead of selected object.
Am tried with stringify also but no luck.
Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select any one</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>

{{selectedItem}}
```

Data:

```
items: any = [{name:'a', rate:20}, {name:'b', rate:36}, {name:'c', rate:42}];
```

Your suggestion are helpfull to me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[value]` on `<select>` works only for string values. For object values it requires `[ngValue]`

```
<option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">
```

Comment: is it possible to put data in data attribute like <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item" data-itemrate="{{item.rate}}">

Comment: For attribute binding you need to add the `addr.` prefix ` `attr.data-itemrate="{{item.rate}}">` or `[attr.data-itemrate]="item.rate">`